# How to securely access API Gateway from a frontend application hosted in AWS amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have the following:

- A Vue.js frontend app hosted in AWS Amplify.
- An API Gateway that triggers several Lambdas that make changes in a MongoDB hosted in an EC2 instance.

My idea is that the frontend approaches the API Gateway and GET/POST data.
The problem is that I would like to make the API Gateway accessible only from my App (nobody could make requests without authorization).

How should I handle it?

- If I provide API Keys to the API Gateway, how do I inject them securely in the frontend app? Those will be accessible to anyone, right? If so, where should I put that API Key? Inside an .env file? Would that be secure enough?
- Using API Gateway authorizers?

I've seen some examples where people place an intermediate backend in Amplify in order to do so, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This answer isn't prescriptive, but hopefully has enough detail and buzzwords to start you on your journey.

Your front-end requests will should an `Authorization` header with a JWT token from Cognito or your auth provider.

API Gateway can wire-up to Cognito (or you can wire-up a "custom authorizer") and only pass-through requests that have a valid token.

Your Lambda will know the user is validated (as a known user or guest) but must still determine if they are *authorized* to perform the action they're attempting. If using something like AppSync, you can pass the user's Authorization header though to the AppSync API and the resolvers can allow/reject based on the authorization rules in your schema. I'm not familiar with EC2 hosted MongoDB, but imagine you'll need to wire it up to your auth so it can behave similarly.

I wouldn't recommend API keys. You can't put them client-side, they need to be managed and rotated, you're letting the "lambda" have permissions instead of the "user", etc.

I do recommend Amplify. You may be able to ditch MongoDB and the EC2 (yuck, you don't want to manage that) for AppSync backed by DynamoDB. And if you also use Cognito, you can do much of the above with very little effort.

**EDIT To address your comment:**
While your website may be hosted on your servers (or your account on a cloud provider's servers), it runs on people's personal devices. The HTTP requests (e.g. REST) your server receives don't indicate they originated from your website and there is no 'link' that ties YOUR front-end to your backend. HTTP does have a `Referer` Header that indicates the webpage the request is associated with, but you can't trust it.

Because your site is public, your API will receive requests from anywhere and everywhere. There is no way to prevent that. You can put less expensive request handlers in front of your API handlers to catch and discard invalid requests (or return cached responses when appropriate).

Your server could require requests include a special header (e.g. an API-KEY) that only your website will include in requests. But anyone can look at your website code and/or the network traffic (even simply via the browser debugging tools) and learn about that secret header.

You can look into XSRF tokens. This is where the front-end provides a unique token when serving a page (usually in conjunction with a form), and it must be included when sending data back to the server or the data will be considered invalid.

Cognito / Amplify will generate tokens for GUEST/un-authenticated users as well. So they can be used for what you want. It doesn't guarantee the requests are coming from your websites's javascript, but it'd be annoying to work around.

You can use CORS in your server responses. That prevents other websites from directly calling your APIs. Your server would still be called and return data, but an unmodified browser will see the CORS header and throw away the data before making it available to the calling javascript.

At the end of the day if your APIs are on the public internet, anyone and everyone can poke them.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for your answer. I get the general idea, but this sounds to me more like a control for authenticated users. I don't want users to sign in. Anyone could use the app, and the app will be fed by API Gateway requests.  I want these requests to be secured and only be used by my frontend (nobody else could make requests to that API). Is in this case Cognito still valid? How would I get that JWT token? Anyone could do the same without my frontend app, right?